# discord.py authorized members

Tags: python, discord.py

I wrote a command to ban members, but anyone can execute this command. I want only authorized people to use this command. (Forgive me if I still wrote the wrong section on the platform)

Comment: People without `ban members` permission will not be able to use the ban command (even through your bot) as far as I think. However if you still want certain people to use this command, you can either use `command.has_role()` or `command.has_permission()` or you can simply copy member's id and use if else statements for checking author's id.

Comment: Hi Mamosko, you should add some more details about what you are doing and what you have tried to resolve the issue. It would help us help you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure only certain people can execute the command, do the following:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(your_permission=True)  # I'll give a list of permissions down below
```

Or, alternatively, you can make people with only a certain role can execute a command, do the following:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('YOUR ROLE HERE')  # This will allow only people with the given role to execute the command
```

Or you can do this, if you want people with a range of roles to be able to execute the command:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Role1', 'Role2', 'Role3')  # Anyone with any one or more of these roles can execute the command. You can have more than 3 roles stated, or less. If you only have one stated, then it may be better to use the way above
```

---

As stated above, I would provide a list of permissions here. These are a few:

```py
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True, kick_members=True, ban_members=True)
```

Permissions are usually just the permissions that you may give a role, but an underscore replacing the spaces between the words.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `checks` are for. A `check` is a function that gets `ctx` as input & returns `True` if the command can be executed, or `False` when it can't.

API docs with examples & explanation on how to create & use them: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.check

Either that, or an `if-statement` at the top if you function that `return`s when the user isn't allowed to execute it. Checks are cleaner though, so opt for those.

Answer (score 0):

Under `@client.command():` please put the following code:

`@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)`

This will make sure only users that have the ban_members permission can execute the command.